# Remove only a certain part of a sentence in quotations

Tags: python, regex

I'm struggling with removing a certain part of a string, and I'm fairly new to regex. I want to remove the part of a string that has a person's name in quotations, "disconnected", and the "concluded by customer" line. An example of a sentence I'm working on is:

```
new_text = "this is the 'ideal' problem 'joe smith' disconnected ('Concluded by customer')."
re.sub(r"\s'([\w\W\d]+)' disconnected \(.*\)[.|\s]*", '', new_text)
```

The result from this is displaying:

```
"this is the"
```

But I'm trying to get:

```
"this is the 'ideal' problem"
```

Any ideas on how I should change my regex pattern?

Comment: So you want the text before the quotations name which is before the word disconnected ?

Comment: @AyodhyankitPaul correct. And yes @DeepSpace, however, I don't know how to achieve this when there are other quotations in the `<text to extract>` field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one possibility:

```
import re

new_text = "this is the 'ideal' problem 'joe smith' disconnected ('Concluded by customer')."
result = re.sub(r"(^.*)\s+'[^']+' disconnected.*$", r"\1", new_text)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
this is the 'ideal' problem
```

Comment: is there any way you could use a `re.sub` instead of `re.findall`? When I use this pattern in a `re.sub` it's not able to get the desired result.

Comment: @Agrosel Yeah I guess, I changed it to use `re.sub` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with `Positive Lookahead (?= disconnected)`

```
import re

pattern=r'\w.+(?=\sdisconnected)'
text="this is the 'ideal' problem 'joe smith' disconnected ('Concluded by customer')."

data=re.findall(pattern,text)[0].split("'")[:-2]
print("'".join(data))
```

output:

```
this is the 'ideal' problem
```